# How do I deselect a single feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mac

In QGIS 2.12.0, I have all the features that intersect with another layer selected by using the Select by Location tool. However, I want to deselect some of these features while keeping the rest selected.

I am using a Mac, and when I hold 'command' down it lets me select multiple features. However, I can't find a corresponding deselect tool, except the Deselect Features from All Layers button which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this (usually just on a smallish number of features) is to open the attribute table, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click (in windows) so perhaps <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + click (for mac) on the left-hand panel that has the feature no. (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4 etc. for each feature line) - i.e. to the left of your first field column or beneath the top left hand square that selects all features.
- Using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + click you can both select and deselect.

Hope this helps a bit.

(*I also wish there was a "Deselect features from THIS LAYER ONLY" feature) ... instead of only "for all layers"! ... i.e. as a button in the map window like there is for "deselect all..."*)

Answer (score 2):

You can deselect in exactly the same way as as you select multiple features (without activating a different tool).  If you want to deselect one feature from a selected group, ctrl-click on the feature (with the select feature(s) tool active) - or on Mac do command-ctrl-click on the feature you want to deselect.  It should leave the others selected.

As a related aside, and I am sure this must be answered elsewhere, but to deselect all features from just one layer, you have two options:

1. Open the attribute table for the layer you want to deselect and click the 'Unselect all' button there (instead of the one in the main QGIS toolbar)
2. With the selection tool active, highlight the layer you want to Unselect, then click anywhere in the map window where there are no features.

Comment: Thanks for your help! On a Mac, command-click adds that feature to your existing selection, but after some experimenting I found that command-ctrl-click will deselect that feature and remove it from your existing selection.

Comment: On Windows ctrl-click does both.  I'll update my answer to clarify for future Mac users though.